# Foreach scope in mongoose find

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Facing problem with scope in mongoose

```
User.findById(req.user.id, (err, result) => {
  var cartProduct = [];
  result.cart.map(async (item) => {
    //item is {
        productId: "product-id",
        quantity: "2"
    //}
    const product = await Product.findOne({ productId: item.productId });
    cartProduct.push(product); //stores
  });
  console.log(cartProduct); //empty
});
```

Please help me

Comment: Please define the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you map the `result.cart` items to async functions but you never actually `await` them.

Try the following:

```
User.findById(req.user.id, (err, result) => {
  var cartProduct = [];
  await Promise.all(
    result.cart.map(async (item) => {
      //item is {
          productId: "product-id",
          quantity: "2"
      //}
      const product = await Product.findOne({ productId: item.productId });
      cartProduct.push(product); //stores
    })
  );
  console.log(cartProduct); //empty
});
```